# A datetime format error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I am getting an exception error, "Input string was not in a correct format." "Make sure your method arguments are in the right format. When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date beforeputting each varibale into the DateTime object".

it is pointing on the last line of this code:

```
cnaIntakeVSOutputDetail_Intake.Add(new IntakeVsOutput(
facility,
UnitRepository.Units(facility).SingleOrDefault(u => u.Code.Equals(reader.To("UNIT_CODE", ""))),
new Patient()
{
     Account = reader.To("PATIENT_ID", ""),
     MRN = reader.To("MRN", ""),
     Name = reader.To("NAME_FULL", ""),
     Room = reader.To("ROOM_BED", ""),
 },
     reader.To("INFO", ""),
     Convert.ToDateTime(reader["TRDATE"]),
     Convert.ToInt32(reader["MENU_ID"]),
     Convert.ToInt32(reader["VALUE"]),
     null, null, null));
```

Comment: what is content of TRDATE field?

Comment: please use reader["TRDATE"].ToString()

Comment: TRDATE - 2009-05-26 00:00:00.000

Comment: I try this but it doesn't compile:   Convert.ToDateTime(reader["TRDATE"].ToString(yyyy-MM-dd"),

Comment: you are missing (") try using that Convert.ToDateTime(reader["TRDATE"].ToString())

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(reader["TRDATE"].ToString()), this compiled but raised same error.

Comment: If TRDATE is a DateTime, why are you trying to convert it to DateTime?  Will casting work?  What is reader?  And what is the To method?

Comment: We are trying to remove the time on the display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reader["TRDATE"]` does not contain a string that `Convert.ToDateTime` could convert into a `DateTime` value.

This might be because it is an empty string or `DBNull.Value` or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

try DateTime.TryParse instade:

```
string dateString;
 DateTime dateValue;
 DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to ensure that your TRDATE column contains values else it will fire the error the input not in correct format. for that you can use the

> string.IsNullorEmpty(reader["TRDATE"].ToString())

method and then you need to parse the values other wise set your default values or leave it null to return type.